# in Cocoa Bindings, when to use "selection" and when to use "arrangedObjects"?

Tags: cocoa, binding

I know (or at least I think I know) that "selection" is essentially one *particular* arrangedObject, but when I'm doing binding I'm always binding one object at a time.  So how do I know when to use "selection" and when to use "arrangedObjects"?

Comment: What do you mean you're only binding one object at a time? What are you binding? A little more detail would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I understand what I was doing wrong.  The "one object at a time" came from not distinguishing between a table column and a text view.  A table column uses arrangedObject, since it contains multiple objects, arranged, while a text view is a single object, so it uses selection.